# Is there a formal way to zeroize in CANopen

Tags: can-bus, canopen

I have a system with multiple subsystems communicating with CANOpen. There is a main unit with a screen (for men-machine interface and stuff) and sub-units for minor operations(like sample button status, manage power, take measurements...).
We defined a CANOpen based communication protocol for this system. Subsystems share their conditions periodically with TPDO messages and do stuff according to main unit's commands sent with RPDO messages. And also some NMTs are in use too.
So I've been asked to add a new command to this protocol, zeroize. This command shall be sent broadcast and it shall cause everybody to delete softwares. What is the right way to do this?
Maybe I can use a RPDO? Are we allowed to define new NMT commands in CANopen? Maybe I can do it with NMT but by using a new commandt hat is not in use already?
Thanks in advance
Ip.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit confusing what you mean with TPDO and RPDO since the main unit's TPDO is going to be the peripheral units' RPDO and vice versa. But yes, the correct way to send out some custom broadcast message would be with a PDO.

Although, depending on what you mean with "delete software", CANopen might provide a mean for it. There are the save (OD 1010h) and load (OD 1011h) registers in the object dictionary. Save is to be used for the purpose of storing all CANopen communication (PDO configuration, mapping etc) in non-volatile memory. And load is used to restore CANopen parameters to factory defaults. These should however not be used to save/load application-specific settings.

You are not allowed to define new NMT commands.

Comment: Hmm OK. I looked for this defining new NMT  commands rule but I couldn't find anything. Can you share reference if it is possible?

Comment: There is no explicit prohibition on it in the standards. But CiA 301 defines only 5 NMT commands. Any extra command you define yourself is not "CANopen". It wouldn't fit the NMT state machine and there is no guarantee how other CANopen devices might react to it. If you're going outside CANopen, why not define your own CAN frame with an unused CAN-ID? That way you're still compliant. And regular CANopen devices will just ignore it.

Comment: @JosSeldenthuis From what I remember from CANopen conformance testing, they don't allow anything that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1):

Objects 1010h and 1011h can be used to reset the values in the object dictionary. If you really want to delete the software, the firmware upgrade protocol from CiA 302-3 might help. Writing 00h (Stop program) followed by 03h (Clear program) to object 1F51h sub-index 1 on the slave will delete the application. Whether it's actually "zeroed out" depends on the implementation. You'll need two SDO requests per slave for this though. The standard specifies that object 1F51h cannot be PDO mapped. Although that requirement may not be enforced for your devices, in which case you could achieve broadcast "zeroing" with two PDOs.